# memory runs out when using fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have noticed on IE8/9 that everytime I click a fancybox link it uses more memory
and doesn't give it back when the box is closed.
Is this supposed to happen?

Am using fbox 2.1.4 and jquery 1.9.1

I have some users that click on 30+ fbox links and then start running out of memory

Comment: Please [don't add signatures or taglines to your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Comment: How much memory are we talking about here?

Comment: depends on the iframe content, but with fresh IE - the IE memory
is at 134MB 
first fbox        = 152MB
second fbox open  = 175MB

Comment: on close the memory usage doesnt go down - just stays at 175MB

Comment: Are you opening `iframes` with fancybox? if so, it seems to be an IE issue rather than fancybox. Check http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2714930 and this none-answered question that already raised the issue http://stackoverflow.com/q/8577322/1055987

Comment: Also check this answer if that helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/11514423/1055987

Comment: Hi JFK - yes the fancybox is loading the content in iframes,
and appears the above posts outline the issue im having.
cant believe there is no "easy" solution - might have to drop the fbox and use jquery dialog instead
thanks for your help

Comment: will try using the func in http://stackoverflow.com/a/11514423/1055987

Comment: @zima10101 : using jQuery dialog won't make much of a difference if you still plan to open iframes. As mentioned, is an IE vs iframes related issue.

Comment: true - knew using iframes was a bad way to go

Comment: FYI have got round to changing fancybox type to 'ajax' and the issue is still there.
Uses extra 8mb every time it opens, then doesn't give back.