# iframes - change src vs destroy? memory-wise

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe, memory-leaks

In a large web-app I'm currently working on the main content view is an iframe element with large jsp generated pages inside.
I know using the iframe is not the best idea, but that's a constraint we have to deal with at the moment.

I noticed IE8 is consuming a large amount of memory over time and after a little investigation found its a known issue:
[Is it possible to use iframes in IE without memory leaks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8407946/is-it-possible-to-use-iframes-in-ie-without-memory-leaks)

the semi-solution posted there states that purging the iframe before removing it might help.

my question is what is a better practice: destroying the iframe on each view (with purging/without), or changing its src attr?
will I have the same memory-leak?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From reading the linked solution it seems that changing the src is not enough, because navigating will have the same memory leak. I think you should try the purge upon navigation.

Comment: What does 'purge' mean in this context?

Comment: It means cleaning up the resources taken by the iframe before removing/pointing it to blank. See the link in the question for more details:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8407946/is-it-possible-to-use-iframes-in-ie-without-memory-leaks